# How to change toolbar back button icon in android material components

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx, material-components-android, material-components

I would like to change the default navigate up icon (back button icon) to my custom icon. I not using a drawer, just a simple toolbar and material components

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible. Have you looked into the documentation of toolbar?

Comment: Yes I did, what I could only find was `navigationIcon` attribute but this doesn't change the navigate up icon

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using a **`Toolbar`** to **change the icon** just use:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.xxx);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx4);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

If you are using the **`ActionBar`** you can use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.xxx);
```

You can also change it overriding in your app theme the `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/...</item>
  </style>
```

If you are using the **Navigation Components**, currently there isn't a way to customize the HomeAsUpIndicator icon, and it is an expected behavior with the Up button displayed when you are on a non-root destination.
There is a workaround adding an `addOnDestinationChangedListener` after your setup method and checking the destination.
Something like:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(
        new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_xxx) {
                    //With ActionBar                        
                    //getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.xxxx);

                    //With a Toolbar
                    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx);
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i don't want to change the color, I want to change the ICON to my custom icon

Comment: @JamaMohamed Sorry my bad. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was having problems making it to work. I was using the navigation component and later set it up with the toolbar. Your solution worked when I remove the `setupWithNavController` for the toolbar. Is there a way to change the icon when setting up the toolbar with the navigation component

Comment: @JamaMohamed Updated the code also with Navigation Components

Comment: Be careful first call setupWithNavController() and only thenafter addOnDestinationChangedListener().

Comment: Thank you, that `Navigation Components` workaround saved my day

Comment: It will replace Menu (Hamburger) icon too! I need to change only Back icon. But with your solution there will be always Back button! Android with navigation component automatically handles if toolbar should show Menu icon or Back icon

Comment: This is so wrong. You are talking about methods to set some additional icon which has nothing to do with Back button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812362/how-to-set-my-own-menu-and-back-icons-for-toolbar

Answer (score -1):

If you have created a toolbar and set it as an `ActionBar` like below

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

You have two options in setting a custom icon:

**Option 1**

```
toolbar?.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.homeNavigationIcon)
```

**Option 2**

```
supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.homeNavigationIcon)
```

Comment: No... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69812362/how-to-set-my-own-menu-and-back-icons-for-toolbar